# How do I overcome my nervousness while facing an interview?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, careers

Recently I faced an interview and it was VERY bad from my perspective. I started well but at later stage (and that was too early :(  )  I was unable to answer few questions that I really dont know and then my nervousness over ruled and questions that was supposed to be answered I just say NO to them(really a bad on).

How could I overcome crucial time nervousness( specially interested in interview supported answers)

Comment: [This answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/8936/2322) may be quite helpful. The asker has a different problem but the solution is the same: practice.

Comment: @RhysW Thx but just a thing to know that how much time delay be accepted between the question and the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I don't think this question is an exact duplicate of the other question. In the other question, the asker had trouble with non-technical questions during interviews. This question is that the OP starts to be nervous after he is asked questions he really doesn't know the answers during the interview.*

---

As enderland pointed out, the solution is: **practice**.

In addition to practice, you have one more problem you need to overcome, that is, **fear of failure**.

Everybody has different personalities. I don't know about others. I also had the same problem before. The way I dealt with it was to keep telling myself to **calm down**. This is not the only company that has job opportunities. Even I miss this one, I have others available. I may not know the correct answer of this question, but I certainly know the answers of the other questions, etc.

In other words, **keep your self-confidence up**. If you look down yourself, how do you expect they would hire you? So, **be confident** is the solution to the fear.

Again, this is my way to deal with it. In order to be confident, you need to have a lot practice and also good working skills.

Comment: what type of practice ? practice for the questions that I could make or it some other practice bwfore going for an interview?

Comment: To clarify what scaahu and @enderland meant by practice: your behavior is induced by stress, and is symptomatic for the 1st one of 3 stages (newbie). The 2nd stage (veteran) comes after going to several interviews. As soon as you get accustomed to being interviewed, you'll experience high anxiety **before** the interview, but significant anxiety reduction **after it starts**. To build up this behavior, choose several companies you won't work at for target practice and go through the interviews there first, before turning to the companies you'd like to work at.

Comment: @swapnesh Always remember that you can't know everything, no one does. Be honest when you face a question you don't know the answer or the question is unanswerable. Just say you don't know the answer and get yourself ready for the next question. This takes a lot practice.

Comment: @scaaahu thx for the advice..I will surely keep the things and suggestions in my mind next time

Comment: @swapnesh You're welcome. Good luck.

Comment: Concerning being honest, as mentioned above, my suggestion is to also be honest about your nervousness. Don't try to hide it.

Comment: @feklee after having an experience (+2years) is it ok to show nervousness? If i was a fresher then this thing counts + (honesty with nervousness but after experience not sure) let me now your thoughts

Comment: @swapnesh I'm not a recruiter. This is just personal experience. I noticed that not worrying about signs of nervousness (sweaty palms, shaky hands, etc.) is a technique that actually makes me relax somewhat and concentrate on what is important. That holds true for all kinds of situations, with a few exceptions: Shaky hands for example are a disadvantage when holding a microphone.

Comment: @swapnesh 1. Look for interview questions on the internet, both technical and "soft", ( like "what would you say your biggest flaw is?"). Write down answers to each of these. 3. Use a video camera to record yourself giving the answers. 4. Watch the video and see if you're doing anything that looks nervous. (Looking down, fidgeting, etc.) Keep repeating the exercise until you have a video that looks like someone you'd want to hire. (edit: realized that I'm saying this: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/how-to-answer-critical-non-technical-questions-in-an-interview/8936#8936)

Answer (score 6):

The other answer doesn't really give a good explanation of how to actually resolve the situation.

From a [previous answer of mine](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/8936/2322):

> > How can I develop the confidence to answer questions like:
>
> There is no magical "instant confidence" anyone can give you.
>
> > I know you cannot answer these questions for me but I do not know how to prepare good responses for these types of questions, and then
> >     deliver them with confidence during the interview.
>
> You need to practice.
>
> Seriously.
>
> If you've been at the same company your entire career you probably
>   have interviewed only a handful of times and not at all recently.
>   Unless interviewing comes naturally to you, you won't feel comfortable
>   at all, and if your only opportunities to interview come in the actual
>   interviews which happen only once every few years, you'll never
>   develop the skills to do so (especially if you don't feel confident in
>   the first place).
>
> You need to practice answering them. Do this in three steps.
>
> 1. Find lots of questions like that which are hard for you to answer. The Internet makes this really easy
> 2. Write out short answers to them
> 3. Have people (family, friends, [Toastmasters](http://www.toastmasters.org/), a [rubber
>      duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html),
>      or the wall) ask you them and get familiar answering them

This is all just as relevant here.

---

From your comment and more specifically for your situation:

> but just a thing to know that how much time delay be accepted between the question and the answer

You can take time to answer questions. You do not have to respond immediately. You can take time to think through them - seriously. I've had offers for jobs where I was asked something, and took some time to think and said something like, "let me think for a bit" and spent a few seconds thinking.

Generally this is not seen as a bad thing at all.

If this is a serious problem for you to actually do in interviews, teach yourself to count to 1 after every question you get asked - say "one-one-thousand" in your head each time you get asked a question. If this isn't enough make it a bit longer (and you can say whatever you want, really, you could say "I can totally answer this - I'm not nervous!" if you think this helps).

Find a friend who knows your technical knowledge and have them ask you questions of things you don't necessarily know to get used to this. Dress up as if you are interviewing if you want.

The overall point is - you won't magically get better at interviewing and high stress situations without some practice.

Comment: Awesome!! Awesome!! Awesome!! feel i can upvote it multiple times

Answer (score 3):

I can tell my experience of How I am doing it on the interview day. There is a hidden trick in it. If you go with the mindset **I don't care even if I don't get the job or I get nervous **, You can do better at interviews. In my experience, even though I get nervous few times, I recover and finally will create a lasting impression on the interviewer. Since I set my mind to accept the failure, I am more free to express myself. 
If the requirements and skills are matching, I usually get the offer.

(An ideal example for this When You go for interview having a good job at hand.In this case,You go very relaxed because you go with the mindset that You are not worried about the result )

There was another time where I desperately wanted the job and in the interview I tried to impress the interviewers and ended up telling one lie and became nervous after that. I failed in that interview.

In short, the key for my success is the mindset I go in before the interview.

Comment: common but effective :)

Comment: This.  You have to not care whether or not you get the job.  It works for me :)