# How to answer interview question "is there part of this job you might not like"?

Tags: interviewing

Basically the question was "is there anything about the type of work you applied for that you do not like?". For more context, I applied for a tech support position. The interviewer had asked me to talk about my previous related experience. After I finished giving a synopsis she asked "if there is any part of this that you don't like?". I tried giving an answer as I would to "tell me about your weaknesses" but this didn't really fit. How should I answer a question similar to "based on what you envision this job to be, is there a part you don't think you like?".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere bit hard to know after just one interview. Even if the answer is yes, how should it be phrased to make it positive? For example when replying to "what are your weaknesses" you wouldn't just give a list but explain how you overcome them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tough curveball interview questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/tough-curveball-interview-questions)

Comment: One word - truthfully

Answer (score 24):

In an interview you should answer all questions honestly and constructively.

For a question like this, a good approach would be to pick out something that you don't like, and explain how you'd deal with your dislike in a professional way.

For example:

> I find it quite frustrating dealing with network issues. I love the software side of things, but for some reason the physical network stuff just doesn't click with me. I've found it helps to build up a document of common issues I come across, and I do quite a lot of reading in my own time to try and address this.

Comment: +1 for _explain how you'd deal with your dislike in a professional way_. There will always be something you dislike, even if it's just the view from the carpark. How you deal with it / minimize the effects is what's important. Plus they might want to know whether candidate A or B is the better fit, all else being equal.

Comment: @Justin Years and years ago I got a junior level job by being honest that I didn't know the answer to a question I was asked in an interview and explaining how I'd find out the answer if I was faced with it in a workplace situation. The interviewers were gobsmacked and later told me that that particular answer put me head and shoulders above the other candidates. That's always stuck with me, and I've used that attitude in every interview since. It seems to work really, really well.

Comment: @PlayerOne I have had the exact same experience and I place a high value on this type of answer when I give interviews... +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

Those are the kind of questions I try and avoid asking in an interview. Tends to only produce a meaningless/humblebrag type answer 'Oh I think going home will be the worst part of each day!' or ends up with a nervous, but otherwise good candidate talking themselves out of the job.

As they do come up though, I think the best approach is to try and identify something that you know truthfully you don't like (I think I said writing documentation last time I had something similar), but make it clear you are professional enough to recognise it's part of the job and you won't put in any less effort.

Comment: In contrast to your approach, I like behavioral questions like this because it can help show general fit - you get a good idea of someone's personality, **and more importantly their self awareness.**

Comment: @dwizum do you think self-awareness is positive and important?

Comment: I think self-awareness is important for growth, and employees who can grow are valuable - versus people with low self-awareness who may be (ignorantly, innocently) making the same mistakes over and over without the opportunity to identify them and improve. You can't identify and learn something if you think you already know it (or if you don't realize you don't know it), and you can't improve a skill if you think you're already great, or at least good enough, at it.

Comment: Fair point. Self awareness is important, and behavioral questions can be valuable, but still don't like this exact one! Something more like 'How do you approach parts of the job you don't enjoy' would be less likely to have candidates backing themselves into a corner at least. I am very much talking about interviewing more junior employees though - for more senior/experienced hires should be able to handle these questions easily.